# Alexa HTML Web API "Alexa.create not a function" Error on Echo Show 10

Tags: javascript, html, alexa-skills-kit

This is the HTML code for my Alexa Skill.

```
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.html.games.alexa.a2z.com/alexa-html/latest/alexa-html.js"> 
  </script >
</head>
<body>
var alexaClient;
Alexa.create({version: '1.0'})
    .then((args) => {
        const {
            alexa,
            message
        } = args;
       alexaClient = alexa;
       document.getElementById('debugElement').innerHTML = 'Alexa is ready :)';
     })
     .catch(error => {
        document.getElementById('debugElement').innerHTML = 'Alexa not ready :(';
     });
</body>
```

Works fine on Echo Show 8 and Echo Show 5 but Echo Show 10 gives an error for the same code. It says "Alexa.create is not a function". What can be the possible error?

```
'Alexa.Presentation.HTML': {u'runtime': {u'maxVersion': u'0.2'}
```

This is the request for Echo Show 10 Echo show 8 gives version 1.1

Can this be the possible issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with maxversion '0.2'. After device update its works fine

Answer (score 0):

In the Amazon documents, it's like that:

```
    "device": {
  "deviceId": "amzn1.ask.device.XXXX",
  "supportedInterfaces": {
    "Alexa.Presentation.HTML": {
      "runtime": {
        "maxVersion": "1.0"
      }
  },
    "Alexa.Presentation.APL": {
      "runtime": {
        "maxVersion": "1.4"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

maxVersion is 1.0 so it probably supports create function but echo show 10 has a maxVersion 0.2 so it may not support or have the create function. I don't know the specifics yet.

Can you change

```
'Alexa.Presentation.HTML': {u'runtime': {u'maxVersion': u'0.2'}
```

to

```
'Alexa.Presentation.HTML': {u'runtime': {u'maxVersion': u'1.0'}
```

?
Assuming you use a virtual environment not a real device.

You may want to check [Alexa HTML SDK](https://html.games.alexa.a2z.com/index.html) website.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No, I cannot change the maxversion, that is the response which we get from alexa. I got my skill certified. The problem was with the software version of the device.